# Is it grammatically correct to use "after" or "before" (without a noun) at the beginning of a simple sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to use "after" or "before" at the beginning of a simple sentence? I suppose it is technically an adverb, but it somehow seems like an incomplete preposition phrase to me.
Example 1: We sat in the sun. After, we went swimming. 
Example 2: It was easier to find a job in the past. Before, there was less competition.

Comment: Try *next* or *then* instead of *after*. Which I suppose is a conjunction? [poor attempt at humour, sorry]. Even better, *and then* after a comma instead of the period. You might get away with *later* instead of *after*, as it’s more commonly used to indicate time progression. If you really want to use *After* then say *After that…*.

Comment: I actually really dislike these uses of "after" and "before" (they look like incomplete preposition phrases or botched subordinate clauses to me), but I have read published authors (such as Joyce Maynard) who have used these words in this way, and I was wondering if it grammatically acceptable.

Comment: On that point, I can only speak for myself, and say "NO!" with the reasoning that *before* and *after* are *relative* indicators of temporal relationship, and just don’t work without the prior or succeeding event to compare to. Without a *that* (to point back to the previously-mentioned event) you have to stop yourself short and look back to see what the *After* is comparing to. It’s also hard to read because even when you work that bit out, it inverts the usual sense of *[X] before [Y]* or *[X] after [Y]*.

Comment: tl;dr it’s “hard to read” and annoys old people.

Comment: I'd use `Earlier` and `Later` myself.

Comment: Likely a regionalism.

Comment: The complement in the PP has been ellipted to leave just the head. It's common in informal speech.

Comment: Would you therefore consider it to be a grammatical error in a written academic sentence?

Comment: Not ungrammatical, but I wouldn't recommend it in formal writing. All that's missing is the anaphor "that", i.e. "We sat in the sun. After that, we went swimming", where "that" is anaphoric to "sat in the sun". I can't see any reason to omit it.

Answer (score 1):

*Before* is commonly [used as an adjunct](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/britisch-grammatik/linking-words-and-expressions/before), usually in final position in its clause:

> I've never been to this restaurant *before*, so you may have to help me with the menu.

Your example sentence could be recast accordingly:

> There was less competition *before*.

Your objection then is whether *before* as adjunct may come at the beginning of a sentence rather than at the end. Since the first sentence ends with *in the past*, it makes stylistic sense to begin with *before* to signal the reader that the rest of the clause is also in the past.

This would also hold if you prefer to parse *before* in both sentences above as an adverb rather than an adjunct.

*After*, however, has very few adverbial uses, mostly restricted to *the day/morning after*, and no dictionary I consulted lists a usage as an adjunct.

Instead, *[afterward[s]](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/afterward?s=t)* is the adverb of choice:

> Afterward[s] we went swimming.         We went swimming afterward[s].

In everyday speech, *after* is sometimes used in the sense of *afterward*:

> I would meet people for dinner, the cinema or a gig and if we went to a bar [after](http://www.alustforlife.com/personal-stories/the-bottom-of-the-glass-alcohol-and-mental-health) I would just have a couple of minerals or non-alcoholic beers and then go home.

The upshot is that standard usage would support initial *before* far more readily than *after* in the same position since there already is a related word that does the job perfectly.